# Display last 12 months

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am lookking to display the last 12 months and the data for selected month. If a user selects december 2019, it will dsipaly all months from december 2018 till december 2019.
[image]

```
Example
```

[image]

Here is the pbix file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WBOolZIFNTWQsPt_QvCY5OAmdy80lHzm/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Label_Month table is not connected to your fact table.  Also, click on "Modeling" in the desktop editor and "Manage Relationships"; make sure that the filter value for Label_Month is not limiting your output table.  Make sure that there is an actual date value being selected in Label_Month table; if there is not one add it.  You will do the date limiting in the measure value that you aggregate.  This measure assumes that you are summing, but you can use other operators in Calculate.

> Measure = VAR StartDate = DATEADD(MAX(Label_Month(ActualDate)),-1,year) VAR EndDate = MAX(Label_Month(ActualDate)) RETURN
>     CALCULATE( SUM(Column), FILTER( ALL(Label_Month), Label_Month(ActualDate) >= StartDate && Label_Month(ActualDate) <= EndDate ) )